# Count Distinct measure with average condition

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax

please help my problem related DAX on Power BI.
i have data like below:

```
Area    Task       Progress
1       task 1     100
1       task 2     100
1       task 3     100
2       task 4     100
2       task 5     50
3       task 6     100
4       task 7     100
4       task 8     70
```

i want to create some measure to <kbd>DISTINCTCOUNT</kbd> data tabel area only with all task progress is 100 on the area. My expected result is **measure have value 2** which count data area 1 and 3 (area 2 and 4 having 1 task with progress != 100. I just try with DAX below:

```
TotalArea = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Area, Progress=100))
```

but the **measure result is 4** because all area have 1 task with progress = 100.

could you please help to give me the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count all and subtract the count of areas that have progress of less than 100:

```
Measure = 
VAR _all = 
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Area] )
VAR _incomplete = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Area] ) , 
        'Table'[Progress] < 100
    )
RETURN
    _all - _incomplete
```